# adding token to <a href

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I am trying to add a token to a link that is stored in a string. I currently have it hard coded in as 123 but I am hoping to have the token created dynamically using a Guid. I change the Guid to a string but when I try adding it to the href with + it does not add it to the link. Any suggestions?

```
string html = @"<p>Your password has been reset.Please click the link to create new password.      </p>" + "<a       href=\"http://somewebsite.azurewebsites.net/ResetPassword.aspx?token=123\">Reset Password   Link</a>";
```

Comment: Can you try using String.Format? ex: String.Format("?token={0}", guid.ToString())

Comment: You'll need to escape the internal double quotes.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
Guid newId = Guid.NewId();
string html = string.Format("<p>Your password has been reset.Please click the link to create new password.</p><a href=\"http://somewebsite.azurewebsites.net/ResetPassword.aspx?token={0}\">Reset Password Link</a>",newId);
```

Comment: I'd add a link to the MSDN article on `string.Format`

Answer (score 0):

May be something along the lines like :

```
 string html = @"<p>Your password has been reset.Please click the link to create new password.      </p>" + string.Format("<a       href=\"http://somewebsite.azurewebsites.net/ResetPassword.aspx?token={0}\">Reset Password   Link</a>", "123");
```

And then you can replace the "123" with some variable or token in your case.

Or a more refined string will be to have dynamic URL as well.